# Проблема с структурой массива сделанного из XML

Tags: php, xml

Создаю массив:

```
$tv = simplexml_load_file('output/'.$xml);
```

Прохожу по нему с помощью foreach:

```
foreach ($tv as $tvinfo):
if ($tvinfo['channel'] != ''){
$channel=$tvinfo['channel'];
}
```

Но это только идентификатор канала или тега в котором лежит его значение(я не знаю точно). Пытаюсь получить название, например "Канал 1"(он находится в `[id]`).

```
echo $tv['channel'][0]->display-name;
```

Но никак не пойму как до него добраться. Там на пути лежат объекты, как с ними взаимодействовать я не знаю, а так же я пока не придумал как это все сделать в цикле, получая вместо идентификатора название.

Прилагаю структуру XML массива:

```html
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [source-info-url] => http://cherrytest.com/
            [source-info-name] => CherryTest
            [generator-info-name] => XMLTV/: tv_grab_na_dd.in,v 1.70 2008/03/03 15:21:41 rmeden Exp $
            [generator-info-url] => http://www.xmltv.org/
        )

    [channel] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Канал 1
                        )

                    [display-name] => Канал 1
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Канал 2
                        )

                    [display-name] => Канал 2
                )

        )

    [programme] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [start] => 20161104121212 +0200
                            [stop] => 20161105215224 +0200
                            [channel] => 0
                        )

                    [title] => Передача 1
                    [desc] => Описание отсутствует.
                    [date] => 20161104
                    [audio] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [stereo] => stereo
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [start] => 20161108121212 +0200
                            [stop] => 20161109215225 +0200
                            [channel] => 0
                        )

                    [title] => Передача 2
                    [desc] => Описание второй передачи. Йеее.
                    [date] => 20161108
                    [audio] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [stereo] => stereo
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [start] => 20161112121212 +0200
                            [stop] => 20161113215226 +0200
                            [channel] => 1
                        )

                    [title] => Передача 3
                    [desc] => Описание отсутствует.
                    [date] => 20161112
                    [audio] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [stereo] => stereo
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Сам XML файл:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM 'xmltv.dtd'>
<tv source-info-url="http://cherrytest.com/" source-info-name="CherryTest" generator-info-name="XMLTV/: tv_grab_na_dd.in,v 1.70 2008/03/03 15:21:41 rmeden Exp $" generator-info-url="http://www.xmltv.org/">
 <channel id="Канал 1">
  <display-name>Канал 1</display-name>
 </channel>
 <channel id="Канал 2">
  <display-name>Канал 2</display-name>
 </channel>
 <programme start="20161104121212 +0200" stop="20161105215224 +0200" channel="0">
  <title lang="ua">Передача 1</title>
  <desc lang="ua">Описание отсутствует.</desc>
  <date>20161104</date>
  <audio>
   <stereo>stereo</stereo>
  </audio>
 </programme>
 <programme start="20161108121212 +0200" stop="20161109215225 +0200" channel="0">
  <title lang="ua">Передача 2</title>
  <desc lang="ua">Описание второй передачи. Йеее.</desc>
  <date>20161108</date>
  <audio>
   <stereo>stereo</stereo>
  </audio>
 </programme>
 <programme start="20161112121212 +0200" stop="20161113215226 +0200" channel="1">
  <title lang="ua">Передача 3</title>
  <desc lang="ua">Описание отсутствует.</desc>
  <date>20161112</date>
  <audio>
   <stereo>stereo</stereo>
  </audio>
 </programme>
</tv>
```

Если кому будет полезно, я решил вопрос с атрибутом образом описанным ниже, в остальном большое спасибо @Алексей Шиманский

```
$number = (int) $tvinfo['channel'];                  //конвертировал в int
$real_channel = $tv->channel[$number]->attributes(); //так как у меня цикл и каналы могут повторятся для разных передач я достаю соответствующий канал
$channel=$real_channel;
```

Comment: `echo $tv['channel'][0]->{display-name};`  получится?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский неа

Comment: @Arnial `echo $tv['channel'][0]->{'display-name'};` - ноль реакции

Comment: Можете куда-нибудь под сниппет еще спрятать сам xml?

Comment: `echo $tv['channel'][0]->['display-name'];` ?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский конечно, просто я думал этого хватит. Добавил дату XML файла. И еще раз, мне нужно вытащить значение атрибута: `id="Канал 1"`, как обращаться к атрибутам я не понял пока что, потому пытаюсь хотя бы понять структуру как обратится к самим тегам, типа `display-name`.

Comment: @Levelleor `$tv->channel[0]->{'display-name'};`  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/43dz-nryi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращение к объекту должно быть через стрелку, поэтому `$tv['channel']` неверно. Нужно `$tv->channel`. Тоже самое и внутри, за исключением, когда имя составное. В этом случае надо обращаться как `->{'ИМЯ_ЭЛЕМЕНТА'}`, например

```
echo $tv->channel[0]->{'display-name'};
```

К доступу к атрибутам есть метод `attributes()`. Например доступ к атрибутам `channel[0]` будет выглядеть как

```
$tv->channel[0]->attributes();
```

Итого:

```
// каналы 
foreach($tv->channel as $test) {
    echo 'Название канала: '.$test->{'display-name'} .' <br/>' ;
    echo 'Атрибуты канала: <br/>';
    foreach($test->attributes() as $key => $val) {
        echo $key . ' = ' . $val ."; ";
    }
    echo '<br/><br/>';
}
```

выведет

```
Название канала: Канал 1 
Атрибуты канала: 
id = Канал 1; 

Название канала: Канал 2 
Атрибуты канала: 
id = Канал 2;
```

Comment: Я немного запутался. `display-name` мы вывели, это отлично, но теперь идем дальше. Нужно вывести не все атрибуты, а только один - `id`. Можно как-то обойтись без цикла(ну типа он делает лишние действия), как-то так: `$tv->channel[0]->attributes('id');`?

Comment: Я так понял если атрибут только один, как у меня - работает такой вариант `$tv->channel[0]->attributes();`

Comment: @Levelleor без цикла, в зависимости от версии php можно написать либо сразу `$tv->channel[0]->attributes()['id']`  либо в старой php 5.3 в начале сложить в переменную все атрибуты `$attr = $tv->channel[0]->attributes();` и потом только взять нужный `echo $attr['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
(string)$tv->channel[0]->{'display-name'};
```

В цикле:

```
$tv = simplexml_load_file('output/'.$xml);
foreach($tv->channel as $channel){
    var_dump((string)$channel->{'display-name'});
}
```

или

```
$tv = simplexml_load_file('output/'.$xml);
foreach($tv->channel as $channel){
    $attr = $channel->attributes();
    var_dump((string)$attr['id']);
}
```

[Пример](http://ideone.com/9S4egH)